# Validating Telephone Number in RegEx in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, formik

I'm trying to validate this kind of phone number in regEx in React `(044) 456-7890`.

Check codesanbox here [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-chaum-zzqof?file=/src/PhoneForm.jsx)

**Code**

```
const telRegExp = "(d{3})s*d{3}-d{4}";

let validateSchema = yup.object().shape({
  tel_no: yup.string().matches(telRegExp, "Telephone number is invalid")
});




  <InputMask
      mask="(999) 999 - 9999"
      onChange={handleChange}
      onBlur={handleBlur}
    >
     {() => (
       <TextField
         label="Telephone Number (Ex: (044) 878 - 3900)"
         name="tel_no"
         fullWidth
         variant="outlined"
         helperText={touched.tel_no ? errors.tel_no : ""}
         error={touched.tel_no && Boolean(errors.tel_no)}
       />
     )}
  </InputMask>
```

Comment: Is the sample number the exact format you want to validate for all inputs?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes

Comment: Your current regex `(d{3})s*d{3}-d{4}` is bogus, because you don't escape the metacharacters.  It should be corrected to `\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}-\d{4}`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. Tried it but same thing it still is outputting invalid

Comment: `/\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}-\d{4}/.test("(044) 456-7890")` is working.  There is something wrong with JS code and how you are calling the regex API.

Comment: Perhaps this page can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/how-to-validate-phone-numbers-using-regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}$
```

This matches the given format exactly

https://regex101.com/r/HBvG3K/6

```
\( and \) - To escape () characters and match literally  
\s - space character. If there can be more or no spaces then add * next to \s
\d{} - decimal numbers(0-9) followed by quantifier.

let validateSchema = yup.object().shape({
  tel_no: yup
    .string()
    .matches(
      /^\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}\s-\s\d{4}/g,
      "Telephone number is invalid"
    )
});
```

Comment: Pls check my codesanbox. It still won't work. https://codesandbox.io/s/tel-no-regex2-q4c6x?file=/src/PhoneForm.jsx

Comment: Thanks. Could you the meaning of these `/^\` and `/g` ?.

Comment: `/ /g` - Thats just to enclose the regex and 'g' is a global identifier, useful when you have multiple strings to match. May not be required for you. 

^ and $ represents the beginning and end of string.

Answer (score 0):

To validate the exact number format `(044) 456-7890` I would suggest:

```
\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}-\d{4}
```

### Demo

Comment: Hi! I've made it in codesandbox. Pls check it. It still won't work. Thank you.
https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-chaum-zzqof?file=/src/PhoneForm.jsx

Comment: Please include your JavaScript code in the original question.  There must be some other problem here.

Comment: Ok sure just did it

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be better to use a real phone checking library like: https://github.com/catamphetamine/libphonenumber-js